# How to push child element inside div that's wider than the window?

Tags: html, css

I have a container for all of my content that is 1000px wide and centered vertically and horizontally. The top div is 1600px with a left margin of -300px to match my "full bleed" background image below it. I want my logo to justify left with the image on wide monitors, but push in when the window is less than 1600px. Currently it overflows past the window.

*Note: I would normally run the header outside the container div, but the whole thing is vertically centered and that would throw off the centering, so I'd like to keep the container as the parent.*

http://jsfiddle.net/vgK6s/3/

Comment: Is this what you're talking about? http://jsfiddle.net/vgK6s/2/

Comment: That is similar to what I'm trying to do, however I actually need it to work without absolute positioning. The container is relatively positioned so I can center it vertically. The maximum left limit also needs to apply. Once the window gets beyond 600px, it should no longer left justify with the window, and instead stay 200px left of the content.

Comment: I updated the link on my original post to more accurately portray what I am doing.

Comment: `min-width` and `max-width` on the containing element might work, but I'm still a little foggy what you're actually trying to do in practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to do the way I was trying to do. Once you set the width, you break any connection to the window or frame size, so I had to branch the parent elements off before I set the content width. Here is the result:

http://jsfiddle.net/vgK6s/5/

Answer (score 0):

CSS3 has it's own type of If statements by using the @media tag

```
Do CSS for larger than 1600px

@media screen and (max-width: 1599px) {
    replace CSS with new css if the screen is less than 1600px
}
```

For older browsers, you can replicate this with Jquery

```
//first bind the resize event
$(window).bind("resize", methodToFixLayout);

function methodToFixLayout( e ) {
var winHeight = $(window).height();
var winWidth = $(window).width();
//adjust elements css etc.....
//$("#someDiv").css('someProperty',someValue based on winHeight and winWidth);
}
```

[references](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_mediatypes.asp)

Comment: I need to keep this compliant with older browsers. Most of our customers are in the Asias and using unpredictable browsers.

Comment: Only other option I can see then is using Jquery to catch the window resize event. You can also run the methodToFixLayout on document load for the initial resize fix.

Comment: I noticed Bing's home page seems to do something similar to what I'm trying to achieve. It works with Javascript off, as well.

Comment: Look at their html/css they must be using one of the above css if statements. Only css and javascript can handle event changes on window re size